# Getting 'could not resolve "jest-config" package from the "jest" npm package directory.'

Tags: reactjs, react-native, jestjs, detox

I am getting  "jest-config" package from the "jest" npm package directory error when  I try to run e2e test for android application, I am using  detox test -c android, I installed jest and everything and followed documentation as well.

```js
detox[30627] ERROR: [cli.js] Could not resolve "jest-config" package from the "jest" npm package directory.
detox[30627] ERROR: [cli.js] 
detox[30627] ERROR: [cli.js] This means that Detox could not find it in any of the following locations:
detox[30627] ERROR: [cli.js] * /Users/vamsikrishna/Documents/temp/payzapp/node_modules/jest/node_modules
detox[30627] ERROR: [cli.js] * /Users/vamsikrishna/Documents/temp/payzapp/node_modules
detox[30627] ERROR: [cli.js] * /Users/vamsikrishna/Documents/temp/node_modules
detox[30627] ERROR: [cli.js] * /Users/vamsikrishna/Documents/node_modules
detox[30627] ERROR: [cli.js] * /Users/vamsikrishna/node_modules
detox[30627] ERROR: [cli.js] * /Users/node_modules
detox[30627] ERROR: [cli.js] * /node_modules
detox[30627] ERROR: [cli.js] 
detox[30627] ERROR: [cli.js] HINT: Consider reporting this as an issue at: https://github.com/wix/Detox/issues
```

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, you are missing the `jest-config` package in the node_module.

To solve this, simply install the missing package.

```
npm install jest-config -D
```